# How to add a reference (instead of copy) of a custom iOS framework in a project

Tags: ios, swift, swift-framework

I try to add a custom made framework in a project of me but as a reference.

The reason for this is that I want making changes in the framework and see them in the project without need of delete old framework - copy new one.

But something i am missing since i got the below error

> No such module

The way I add the framework as a reference is to "untick" the "copy if needed" when I drag and drop it.

I am adding the framework inside the "frameworks" folder of the project.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Check, if the framework is added to project's target. Also check the `Frameworks Search Paths` in Target's Build Settings (it should have something like `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Your/Path/To/Framework`.

Comment: everything is fine but still nothing

Answer (score 0):

You should be linking external libraries in the menu by going to the Target’s “Build Phases” and add the library with “link binary with libraries”. This should fix your problem.

[image: linking dependencies]

An alternative suggestion is to use CocoaPods, which are very widely used in iOS development. If you aren't familiar with Cocoapods, its sort of like web development's npm. You turn your custom framework into a Pod and add a Podfile to your iOS app. The Podfile is just a list of external dependencies. If you push a change to your custom framework, all you have to do is run

```
pod update
```

in your command line it will automatically handle the update. This would solve your problem and also keeps your project neat and organized so you don't have to juggle drag and dropping new libraries. CocoaPods also can handle a lot of the other major external libraries you may be using. See the following very easy to follow tutorials:
[creating a pod](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html),
[getting started with cocoapods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html)

Comment: The question is not how to link a lib in a project, but how to reference it and use it without copying it to the project, in order to develop it in parallel

Comment: Are you putting the search path of the reference in "header search paths” in Target’s Build Settings?

Comment: Yes I am adding the full path to the .framework file and it does not work